# How do I maintain interesting prose outside of the introduction/hook when I start getting into my anecdotes?

Tags: narrative, showing-telling, wordcount, flow, prose

This is a personal narrative where I want to narrate my creative side. I start off strong with figurative language, descriptions, and metaphors. But as I get into my anecdote and what I learned from it, I tend to start cutting out flowery language which leaves a very methodical/step-by-step description of an activity that I did. I find it hard to show rather than tell (but also show in an interesting way) when I'm trying to get a point across.

Any tips? I'd be happy to provide any content from my essay as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Pace yourself. Perhaps you're trying too hard at first, and wear yourself out with the effort of it. Take a break and come back to it later. Or perhaps you're getting into it as you write and just start rolling stream-of-consciousness. In this case, don't stop writing, just throw your ideas at the page and don't worry about verbatim.

Either way, that's what the second- and third- and eighty-fifth drafts are for.

Don't expect to get it spot on the first go-round. Take it slow, enjoy the process. Read, refine, repeat. The reader will never know how many tries it took.